# Adding special symbols into HTML

Tags: html

What is considered as best practice for adding special symbols into `HTML`? Using the symbol itself, for e.g. `©` or its code value `&#169;`?

Example 1:

```
<p>Qualcomm©<p>
```

Example 2:

```
<p>Qualcomm&#174;<p>
```

Comment: Differentiate between image size larger and html size smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both have their pros and cons. There isn't a strongly established best practice.

Using a literal character:

- Is easier to read
- Doesn't require developers to remember the character reference code
- Requires fewer bytes/characters to send over the network (or store in a database, which might be more significant).

Using a character reference:

- May be easier to type (depending on the developer's keyboard)
- Is immune to being screwed up by character encoding errors